# Sed command not printing anything out

Tags: sed, command-line

I am trying to find and print 6 letter palindromes using the sed command.

I have a file titled palindrome.txt (contains many 6 letter palindromes) in my Documents folder. While in the Documents directory, I have typed

```
 sed -E -n '/^(.)(.)(.)\3\2\1$/p' palindrome.txt
```

When I press enter it returns nothing, what am I doing wrong?/ Why isn't it printing anything out?

Comment: As you mention 'Documents folder', are  you on a Windows machine? If so your file might need `....\r$/g` at the end, BUT I don't think references to capture groups work inside the match reg-ex, they only work (to my knowledge) inside the replacement part of a sed command. If you have a reference for your usage, please include it in your Q (and then the `\r$` might be your problem). Good luck.

Comment: What happens when you try something simpler, like matching the letter 'a', or matching any repeated letter?

Comment: @shellter Backreferences in the matching part work fine.

Comment: @BenjaminW. : Thanks for improving my `sed` knowledge (truly), my `sed` book is someplace in a box ;-/

Comment: [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output to get the best help. Also tell us if you're running your command from Windows CMD prompt, from cygwin, from bash on Windows 10 or something else.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed. This should work with carriage return from Windows, too:

```
sed -E -n '/^(.)(.)(.)\3\2\1\r*$/p' file
```

Comment: Works for me with `--posix` enabled

Comment: The OP may need to use double quotes as the delimiter in Windows, idk...